# Make your ip open for remote access

Tags: remote-access

I try to enable into my desktop the remote access option to this desktop.

Everything setted ok but when I try to login using the remote access from another place it doesn't work.

The computer is open.

I made a ping to my desktop address and I receive this

```
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

so it seems it is not recacble to public

Any help how can I fix it?

Comment: can you show us the ip or host name of your remote machine?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change settings on your router to forward the request to "this" desktop. And the request, from remote, should be made to the public IP of your router that your ISP assigned to you.

Answer (score -1):

This might not solve your problem, but it does answer the (title of) your question: [try ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)